# Limit proof with absolute value

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to proof the following statement:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L \Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow a}|f(x)|=|L|$$

I know I have to use the limit definition but I can never adapt it with absolute value. I just add the absolute value to the $||f(x)|-|L||<\epsilon$ and by triangle inequality we can conclude the statement but I don't know if I'm right in my conclusion.

Comment: Hint: use the reverse triangle inequality, which gives $\left| |f(x)| - |L| \right| \le |f(x) - L|$.

Comment: Can you write down your proof? Anyway with desiigner's comment you'll have the answer.

Comment: Yes, this uses that $||u|-|v||\leq |u-v|$ for all real $u,v.$ Also for complex $u,v.$

Comment: how about 2 cases, $L\gt 0$ and $L\lt 0$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg and if $L = 0$?

Comment: @fleablood  L=0 requires some work.  f(x) for x near a may have to be split up into positive and negative domains and treated accordingly.

Comment: $||a| - |b|| \le |a-b|$ clears this up nicely.  If for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta$ so that $|x-a|< \delta\implies |f(x) -L|< \epsilon$ then for the *exact* same $\delta, \epsilon$ we have $|x-a|< \delta\implies |f(x) -L|< \epsilon\implies ||f(x)|-|L|| < |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.  And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the "procedure" is valid is the following:

$$||f(x)|-|L|| \leq |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$$

The first "$\leq$" is a consequence of the triangular inequality. Why? You can easily see that if both $f(x)$ and $L$ have the same sign, the first two terms I wrote are actually equal. If they have opposite signs, $||f(x)| - |L|| \leq max\{|f(x)|, |L|\}  \leq |f(x)-L|$

Answer (score 0):

If you accept that for any two numbers $a,b$ that $0 \le ||a|-|b||\le |a-b|$ then this clears this up nicely.

$\lim_{x\to a} F(x) = L$ means by definition; that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta$ so that $|x-a|< \delta\implies |f(x) -L|< \epsilon$.

Then for the *exact* same $\delta, \epsilon$ we have $|x-a|< \delta\implies |f(x) -L|< \epsilon\implies ||f(x)|-|L|| \le |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.

And that is the definition of $\lim_{x\to a} |F(x)| = |L|$.

And that's it.

To prove $||a| -|b|| \le |a-b|$, we know $|m+n|\le |m|+|n|$ by triangle inequality.  Replace $m$ with $a-b$ and $n$ with $b$ and we get $|a|\le |a-b| + |b|$ and $|a|-|b| \le |a-b|$.  As that is true for *all* $a,b$ it will be true if $|a|-|b|$ is positive or negative so it is true that $||a|-|b|| \le |a-b|$.